# bash - create list of lists

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax, append

## Problem

Create an array of arrays, where each row is a row in my dataset `iris-shuffled.txt` with the structure as the following:

```
7.2,3.0,5.8,1.6,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
6.8,3.0,5.5,2.1,Iris-virginica
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,Iris-setosa
7.3,2.9,6.3,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.1,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

My hope was to turn the following pseudo code into bash (to learn how to get better with bash), and this was my hope:

```
 file = data/iris-shuffled.txt
 line_count = NumberOfLines(line);
 container_of_rows = emptyArray();
 for row in file:
     column_container=emptyArray();
    for col in file:
          column_container+=col
    container_of_rows+=column_container
```

## My Best Solution

This doesn't work for storing the second array

## Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Grab the data
file=data/iris-shuffled.txt

# Count the lines
num_lines=$(cat data/iris-shuffled.txt | wc -l)
echo $num_lines

# Store lines into an array                
lines=($(cat data/iris-shuffled.txt))
echo ${lines[0]} #row1
echo ${lines[1]} #row2

mega_list=()
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do

        IFS="," read -ra A_ROW <<< "$line"
        echo ${A_ROW[@]}
        list=()
        for i in "${A_ROW[@]}"
        do
                echo $i."~"
               list+=($i)
        done
        mega_list+=(${list}) #not appending right
done
```

## Output:

```
Iris-setosa.~
5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.4.~
3.7.~
1.5.~
0.2.~
Iris-setosa.~
5.1 3.3 1.7 0.5 Iris-setosa
5.1.~
3.3.~
1.7.~
0.5.~
Iris-setosa.~
7.3 2.9 6.3 1.8 Iris-virginica
7.3.~
2.9.~
6.3.~
1.8.~
Iris-virginica.~
6.7 3.1 5.6 2.4 Iris-virginica
6.7.~
3.1.~
5.6.~
2.4.~
Iris-virginica.~
5.8 4.0 1.2 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.8.~
4.0.~
1.2.~
0.2.~
Iris-setosa.~
```

## Goal

When I run `echo ${mega_list[0]}` my output is just 7.2 (row1 col1), but my hope was to have the whole row as individual array members `[0]7.2 [1]3.0 [2]5.8 [3]1.6 [4]Iris-virginica`

Answer (score 0):

if you do use proper tools for the task, it's not a difficult problem.  For example,

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR,i]=$i} END{print a[4,5]}' file

Iris-virginica
```

depending on what you want to do with the data, you may not even need to store it in an array.

Other example, with slight modification to create the sum of the fields for each unique key

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) a[$NF,i]+=$i; 
            u[$NF]} 
       END {for(k in u) 
              {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%2.1f,", a[k,i]; 
               printf "%s\n", k}}' file

26.1,17.6,7.2,1.2,Iris-setosa
34.3,14.9,28.8,9.7,Iris-virginica
```